# One large plugin vs multiple smaller plugins

Tags: plugins, performance

I'm finding that occasionally (especially on larger sites), there are little bits of functionality that I need that Craft doesn't offer out of the box. The functionality is usually simple and relatively specific, so I find myself quickly writing little plugins that do the job. Currently I've been creating separate plugins for each bit of functionality I need which can result in some sites having upwards of 5 or 6 small plugins, along with any other plugins that I might be using.

This led me to wonder, when it comes to keeping our Craft installs running as cleanly and efficiently as possible, which is better:

a. Having one large plugin that does multiple different, likely unrelated, things.

b. Having multiple smaller plugins, each doing their own thing.

From a development standpoint I find that having separate plugins makes life easier because everything is more organised, but is this having an impact on Crafts performance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe there's any significant impact in having multiple small plugins vs. one big plugin. It's probably safe to say that there is a *small* amount of overhead in loading each plugin separately, but that effect is probably negligible.

Personally, I'd keep all of that functionality combined into a single plugin. You say they are for "different, likely unrelated, things", but I'm guessing that they all serve a larger purpose of handling the **business logic**. If you haven't already, you may want to check out the [Business Logic template](https://github.com/lindseydiloreto/craft-businesslogic), which is designed as a starter plugin for exactly this type of scenario.